# nuxt.js auth always redirect to login instead of allow go to a page with auth: false,

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

Hello I have the following configuration

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
router: {
  middleware: ['auth'],
}
```

```js
auth: {
  redirect: {
    login: '/login',
    logout: '/login',
    home: '/',
  },
  strategies: {
    cookie: {
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        path: '/',
      },
      user: {
        property: false,
        autoFetch: false,
      },
      endpoints: {
        login: { url: '/api/login', method: 'post' },
        logout: { url: '/api/logout', method: 'post' },
      },
    },
  },
},
```

and I the home component it is not necessary be logged, so I set:

```js
export default {
  name: 'IndexComponent',
  middleware: 'auth',
  auth: false,
}
```

but when I try to access to a / auth always redirects to /login.

when I do click nothing happens and nothing is displayed in the console.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `middleware: ['auth']` is on the `router` key right? Is `auth: false` in the `/pages/a.vue` file? Do you see any error? Can you please provide us a [repro]? Do you see anything in your devtools?

Comment: I edited with more details, but the auth: false is in a component, because in the doc the tell "you can set auth option to false in a specific component"

Comment: I tried in a page and that works thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the documentation](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/middleware/), it says

> In case of global usage, you can set auth option to false in a specific component and the middleware will ignore that route.

But by "component", they mean a `.vue` component.
In our case, since we're using Nuxt it still needs to be a page (hence a route in the `/pages/` directory) because this is logical from a router aspect.